# SQL replace char(0)

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

**I try to remove the char(0) character form input Text.
Why is this the result in 3 and 4 cases?**

```
print '1------' + Replace('123 nyon 47647'  ,CHAR(0),'');
print '2------' + Replace('123 nyon'        ,CHAR(0),'');
print '3------' + Replace('nyon'            ,CHAR(0),'');
print '4------' + Replace('ny'              ,CHAR(0),'');
print '5------' + Replace('n'               ,CHAR(0),'');
print '6------' + Replace('yn'              ,CHAR(0),'');

1------123 nyon 47647
2------123 nyon
3------yon
4------y
5------n
6------yn
```

**Thank you!**

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: If it's SQL Server (it looks it) I can't reproduce your results. If you copy and paste your code from here in Stack Overflow back into your query window and run it, does it still do the same thing? You may have some unusual characters in your original code (e.g. something that *looks* like an 'n' but is actually built from a multibyte Unicode sequence.)

Comment: @MattGibson Neither can I, hence was actually what dbms it is.

Comment: I use the SSMS 17.1
database uses the Hungarian_CI_AS collection

Comment: SSMS is the *client* you're using to connect to SQL Server. If you don't know the server version, you can find out by telling us the results of `SELECT @@VERSION`.